# Injections between distinct models of the simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: logic, category-theory, lambda-calculus

Let a model of the simply typed lambda calculus be a Cartesian-closed functor from $C_T$ to Set, where $C_T$ is a free CCC (as in e.g. [this reference](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1077&context=philosophy), p. 83.) The simple case of one or two primitive types with no constants or equations is good enough for me.

I'm interested in finding a pair of models $M, N : C_T → \text{Set}$ and a natural transformation $i : M → N$ such that each function $i_X : M(X) → N(X)$ is injective, but not every $i_X$ is surjective. Do such natural transformations exist?

Comment: I still don't know the general answer to this question, but one thing that I think we have established is that for any such $i : M → N$, if $i_X$ is injective but not surjective, then $M(X)$ must be infinite. This follows from the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208850/distinguishing-powers-of-finite-functions/2209193#2209193), together with the fact that for each $k$, the $k$th-power function is in the image of $M$.